# Adding values from select dropdown react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, state

I have two React Components. The Value Components has a data, that is passed as a props to Numbers Components.

```
class Values extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      values: [
        {
          name: "A",
          numbers: [
            {
              number: 30
            },
            {
              number: 40
            },
            {
              number: 50
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "B",
          numbers: [
            {
              number: 20
            },
            {
              number: 30
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { values } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {values.map(value => (
          <Numbers key={value.name} value={value} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The Numbers Components renders two select dropdowns. I want to be able to choose the two values and store the sum in the Component's state and of course the sum should change as I select other values.

```
class Numbers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      sum: 0
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {};

  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{value.name}</p>
        <select onChange={this.onChange}>
          {value.numbers.map(item => (
            <option value={item.number} key={item.number}>
              {item.number}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In your `onChange` method, you need to grab the values from any select elements that you have rendered. You can use a ref to easily find the elements on the page and grab the current values from them. It's then a case of multiplying them and setting the state appropriately. See refs documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have state like `dropdownValues` which can be array of strings and there should be a `onChange` function in `Values` component and pass this function in to `Numbers` component. Numbers component should send value and index in the `onChange` prop as argument. Then in parent component array `dropdownValues` can be updated of that index of component. Then when we would have array containing values, we can sum them.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to lift the state up and let your `Values` component know inside its own state what are the number selected by each of your selects.

```
class Values extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      values: [
        {
          name: "A",
          selected: 0, // The selected number for this select will be held in memory here
          numbers: [
            {
              number: 30
            },
            {
              number: 40
            },
            {
              number: 50
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "B",
          selected: 0, // The selected number for this select will be held in memory here
          numbers: [
            {
              number: 20
            },
            {
              number: 30
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  // Rest of your component
}
```

Then you need to pass down to your `Numbers` component a way to modify the state of `Values`; for example you can pass a method that will modify the state of your `Values` component.

```
class Values extends React.Component {
 // Code...

  // This will be passed down to Number component in the render method
  selectNumber = (name, number) => {
    this.setState({
      values: this.state.values.map((value => {
        if (value.name === name) {
          return {
            ...value,
            selected: number
          }
        }

        return value;
      }))
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { values } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        // WE PASS IT DOWN HERE
        {values.map(value => (
          <Numbers 
            key={value.name} 
            value={value}
            onSelect={(number) => this.selectNumber(value.name, number)}
            />
        ))}
        <h1>sum: {sum}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally in your `Values` render function you need to sum all the selected numbers of each of your selects that live in your state and display them.

```
class Values extends React.Component {
  // Code ...

  render() {
    const { values } = this.state;
    const sum = values.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.selected, 0) // We make the sum
    return (
      <div>
        {values.map(value => (
          <Numbers 
            key={value.name} 
            value={value}
            onSelect={(number) => this.selectNumber(value.name, number)}
            />
        ))}
        <h1>sum: {sum}</h1> {/* Display the sum */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here's a working codepen I made by tweaking your code.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Erxoez)